# JPasswordField not working properly in JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablecelleditor, jpasswordfield

I'm using `JPasswordField` as `JTable` cell editor in a column. 
It works fine while entering text; but after moving the cursor to another cell, it displays simple text.

So what can I do to keep text hidden while moving in other cells? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The table uses a different component for the editor vs the regular cell renderer. You need a custom TableCellEditor that contains a `JPasswordField`.